# CodeIgniter Rest API (Phil Sturgeon) - How to chop up a very large api file

Tags: api, codeigniter, rest

I have been building a rest api (using Phil Sturgeons Codeigniter-Restserver) and Ive been sticking closely to the tutorial at:

```
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/
```

in particular Ive been paying attention to this part of the tutorial:

```
function user_get()  
{  
    // respond with information about a user  
}  

function user_put()  
{  
    // create a new user and respond with a status/errors  
}  

function user_post()  
{  
    // update an existing user and respond with a status/errors  
}  

function user_delete()  
{  
    // delete a user and respond with a status/errors  
}
```

and Ive been writing the above functions for each database object that is accessible by the api, and also:

```
function users_get()  //    <-- Note the "S" at the end of "user"
{  
    // respond with information about all users
}
```

I currently have approximately 30 database objects (users, products, clients, transactions etc), all of which have the above functions written for them, and all functions are dumped into /controllers/api/api.php, and this file has now grown to be quite large (over 2000 lines of code).

QUESTION 1:

Is there a way to split this api file up, into 30 files for example, and keep all api functions relating to a single database object in a single place, rather than just dumping all api functions into a single file?

QUESTION 2:

I would also like to keep a separation between my current model functions (non-api related functions) and the functions that are used by the api.
Should I be doing this?
Is there a recommended approach that I should use here? For example should I write separate models that are used by the api, or is ok to keep all model functions (both non-api functions, and api functions) for a given database object in the same file?

Any feedback or advice would be great..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create api controllers the same way you do regular controllers; you can do the same with models.

```
application/controllers/api/users.php

class Users extends REST_Controller{
    function user_post(){
        $this->users_model->new_user()
    ...

 POST index.php/api/user
```

--

```
application/controllers/api/transactions.php

class Transactions extends REST_Controller{
    function transaction_get(){
        $this->transactions_model->get()
    ...

GET index.php/api/transaction
```

> I would also like to keep a separation between my current model functions (non-api related functions) and the functions that are used by the api.

I don't see why you couldn't use the same methods so long as they return what you need.